# html5 date textbox- block future dates (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have an asp:textbos with textmode="Date" which turns the textbox into a date picker, how can I block the future dates from the current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [max](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.max) attribute to restrict the future date to be selected.

```
<input type="date" max="2013-11-20" value="2013-11-20" />
```

You can set the current day by either of these way.
1. using code behind

```
dateInput.Attributes["max"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

2. using markup

```
<input type="date" max="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>" />
```

Yes but after this, you can still select the future date using up arrow, so we can put some css trick to hide that something like this

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWHy9/2/)

Comment: If that is the max date, which is today, how will I select future dates when it turns tomorrow

Comment: it worked fine, but it still accepts future dates when I click the up arrow on the date picker.

Comment: thanks for the update, where will i put the css trick? will i declare it as css class?

Comment: @JbMeris no need to declare it as class as I have use `input` selector so it will work without giving the class. You just need to put in css section.

Comment: i made it work already, thankyou very much for your update and help